# Android Real Time Chart for acquired data

Tags: android, eclipse

I have to develop an android application able to acquire data and chart them in real time.

Now, on `Android` Platform there are not built-in graphical libraries, however It is open source, so there are many libraries you can download and install.

Many of these are not able to perform real time chart, and the most part lacks of tutorial and code samples, as a consequence I don't know which I could choose.

I have just tested Android Plot but the `graphic thread` clashed with the thread of `acquisition and the main thread`, causing a `deadlock` and I didn't know why.

I found on a web forum that this library doesn't fit very well with real time chart, so I decide to give up it.

I would be grateful if you advice me which library is more suitable for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this although a technically possible solution would be to use [AJAX-y requests](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI) in combination with the [Google Charts Query Wrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#querywrapper)?

Could be awesome but this means your app would only be able to chart when connected to the internet. Where is the data being stored? Online or in a local SQLite database? The query wrapper chart would be less appropriate if you were just reading your data out of a local database but the approach (AJAX & Google Charts) would be sweet.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting

Well, I get data from bluetooth connection. One datum at a time. Then I add it on a buffer and I send an ack to the data transmitter. When the transmitter receives the ack, It sends another datum and so on.

I would like to plot them real time as they come. 

Unfortunately I can not rely on the internet for the scenario in which my application is running.

There are many graphic libraries on the web and I don't want to choose one at random (expecially because not all are fit for this problem, i saw)

Comment: I see. If nothing suites or works quite as well as you hoped then you could always give it a go yourself! [This tutorial](http://blog.gafmediastudio.com/2010/04/01/draw-a-pie-chart-with-android/) shows you how to use the View Canvas. Doesn't look awfully difficult (famous last words) and avoids the bulk of the libraries...